# Ubuntu - Prevent Linux/Apache users from listing anything but their home directory with PHP

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu, permissions

Long story short, I'm in the early stages of building a small web hosting server. When I create a new site for a customer this happens:

- A new Linux user is created with a home directory and /sbin/nologin
- The user is added to group sftpusers
- A public_html is created in the users home directory
- A new Apache Vhost is created
- The site is started and the process is running as the new Linux user using mpm-itk and AssignUserId

All well so far. The user can only sftp in to the home directory and put his files there. The user can't navigate outside the home directory when using a SFTP client like WinSCP or similar.

The problem is that they can list stuff outside the home dir with a bit of php. This will list everything in /etc/:

```
$scan = scandir(/etc);
foreach ($scan as $i) {
echo $i;
}
```

This is my problem and it needs to be dealt with, but I don't really know how.

My /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
Subsystem       sftp    internal-sftp
Match Group sftpusers
    ChrootDirectory /home/%u
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    AllowTCPForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
```

Please let me know if additional information is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by using [open_basedir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir)